# problem when updating my sqlite3 version (mac)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

i download sqlite3 version - 3.7.5 and puted it in the usr>bin folder but when i run in the treminal "sqlite3 -version" its tell me the version is: 3.6.12

what shoud i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type 'which sqlite3' to find out where the offending version is installed.

Comment: /usr/bin/sqlite3
this is the place when i open this file i see the good sqlite3 version - 3.7.5

Comment: so /usrb/bin/sqlite3 and just sqlite3 gives different versions? :)

Comment: yes.. when i type in the terminal sqlite3 its showing me the 3.6.12 version.. not the 3.7.5..

Comment: what happens when you type /usr/bin/sqlite3 ?

Comment: gal-harths-iMac:~ galharth$ /usr/bin/sqlite3 -
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>

Comment: now i moved to the desktop sqlite3 (the good version) and its stil working.. wierd.. what shoud i do?

Comment: Looks like you have not really installed it to the right place

Comment: so how do i change the place i installed it?